# SSIS parameters not found in connection manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've deployed some packages to the server with our CI/CD chain.
It sets up an environment file with all the parameters we configured.

When we want to execute the the packages (either through a job or manually), we specify to use the environment file. The execution prompt doesn't complaint about any missing parameters.

Then when the execution is started, it fails immediately because a parameter wasn't present.

Here are some screenshots of the prompts and errors:

[image: Execution prompt]

[image: Connection manager setup]

All these parameters are definitely present in the environment file. When the package is run like this, then this is the result:

[image: Error message]

This is our structure:

[image: File structure]

When we don't let the connection parameters use the environment parameters, then everything runs fine.
So the real question is: Why can't the parameters for the connection manager be found at runtime?

Comment: Did you try configuring your SSIS Project with a reference to `.\Test` instead of `Deployed\Test`?

Comment: @Tyron78 No, but it's a dropdown. I can't write my own path to it. Also, the normal parameters (first image) are being found.

Comment: Yes, it is dropdown during execution - therefore I asked for the configuration of your SSIS project. If you go to the SSIS Catalogue and do a right click on your project, you should have a context menu displaying (beside others) "Configure". There you can go to "Reference" - aand there you can add the mentioned reference.
I don't know, why other parameters are found - or better: why they are mapped. We expereienced similar problems when scripting the parameter assignment - there is no  validation against the environment at this point, so with a script, you can assign wrong parameters

Comment: @Tyron78 I've tried what you suggested, but that sadly didn't change anything. The same error occurs. In both cases I can see the 'Parameters Used' section in the report and it correctly displays all parameters. So at that level it works. They just aren't mapped to the connection manager properties.

Comment: and in your environment: are the parameters defined as boolean? As long as the parameter is not defined as boolean, the configuration does not support the use of environments (the option is simply disabled).

Comment: @Tyron78 I had to check that because it's a good suggestion, but yes, the types are ok.

Comment: if you go to the configuration again and into the tab for connectionmanagers: can you assign the same environment-variables there (you don't have to save this change - simply press the `...` next to the default value and then try to assign an environment variable)?

Comment: @Tyron78 Yes, that works just fine. I can see all boolean parameters for the ConnectByProxy field and select them. The string fields accept all string parameters and they are all visible.

Comment: String parameters? I might be mistaken, but shoundn't boolean parameters in SQL / SSIS be set to 0 or 1?

Comment: No, I mean... There are multiple parameters, some are boolean and some a strings. That all works like you'd expect. In a boolean field I can select all boolean parameters from the environment file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224411/discussion-between-tyron78-and-geoxion).